# When run my Cron jobs i received below email

Tags: php, cron

I wrote a function using PHP. When it's run using Cron jobs it's have few issues.
When it run normally (without Cron jobs it's working fine) any idea.

```
<?php
require "PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php";
require "PHPMailer/src/OAuth.php";
require "PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php";
require "PHPMailer/src/POP3.php";
require "PHPMailer/src/Exception.php";
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

This is part of my code

This is issue when this run using cron job

> ?php: No such file or directory
>
> line 2: include: command not found
>
> line 3: include: command not found
>
> line 4: include: command not found
>
> line 5: include: command not found
>
> include: command not found
>
> line 7: include: command not found
>
> line 9: use: command not found
>
> line 10: use: command not found

Any idea about this

Comment: How do you call your script in crontab?

Comment: Do you have PHPMailer library where you have your cron script? In this case it has to be the same directory. And this looks like you are using some autoloader. If it is composer, you have to have autoload.php added to the top of the cron script and vendor directory should be located in the same directory.

Comment: path to script/robots.php this is the way i call script in my cron job. Yes in that folder there have PHPMailer library.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute the script with a shell interpreter (probably `bash`), but it is written in PHP, not shell!

Change your cron command to explicitly mention PHP:

```
20 21 * * * /path/to/bin/php /path/to/your/script.php
```